# Infinite decimal expression of rational numbers

Tags: divisibility, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

I'm asked to prove that if a non-integer rational number is written as a non reductible fraction $a/b$ and $a,b $are co-primes and $b$ is not multiple of 2 or 5, then the decimal expression of the number is infinite.

I can get as far as proving that if $r$ is a rational number with finite decimal expression,then the decimal expression must be of the form $\frac{a_110^{n-1}+...+a_n}{2^n5^n}$ but altought this proves when the decimal expression is finite, I think is not a good proof, since I'm not using any of the hypothestis.

Could you help me and give me some advice?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what is wanted here.  If $a=2,b=1$, the decimal is certainly finite yet the denominator is not a multiple of $2$ or $5$.  It is certainly true, as you appear to argue, that if the decimal is finite then $10^n\times r$ is an integer for some natural number $n$, thus $b$ is a divisor of $10^n$.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to add that r is not an integer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is a bit of logic.  The given statement is equivalent to

> if $a/b$ is not reducible (that is, $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime) and is not an integer and the decimal of $a/b$ is finite, then $b$ is a multiple of $2$ or $5$.

You have almost proved this.  If the decimal is finite then you have shown
$$\frac ab=\frac{a_110^{n-1}+...+a_n}{2^n5^n}\ .$$
If the numerator and denominator have any common factors, cancel them to get $b$ in the denominator: then $b=2^l5^m$ for some $l,m$ and since $b>1$, it is a multiple of $2$ or $5$.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'd like to remove your first paragraph now that the statement in the question has been corrected.

Comment: @DavidZ Done.  Thanks for alerting me.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Suppose we have that $x$ has a finite decimal expansion, allowing us to write
$$x=\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i\cdot 10^i$$
for some $n,m$ and  $a_m,a_{m-1},\dots, a_n$. We then have that
$$10^{|m|}x\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Conversely, if $10^{p}x\in \mathbb{Z}$ for some $p$, then we have that $10^{p}x$ has a terminating decimal expansion, i.e.
$$10^{p}x=\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i\cdot 10^{i}$$
and so
$$x=\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i\cdot 10^{i-p}$$
has a terminating decimal expansion. Thus

> $x$ has terminating decimal expansion if and only if $10^{m}x\in\mathbb{Z}$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

If every terminating decimal, written as a fraction $a/b$, has $b$ divisible by $2$ or $5$, then a fraction $a/b$ where $b>1$ is not divisible by $2$ or $5$ must not correspond to a terminating decimal.  But it has some decimal expansion, so that must be non-terminating.